# How to solve tkPDFViewer error: 'Page' object has no attribute 'getPixmap'. Did you mean: 'get_pixmap'?

Tags: python-3.x, tkpdfviewer

I am viewing pdf file in python. I use tkPDFViewer library however getting error `AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tkPDFViewer\tkPDFViewer.py", line 46, in add_img pix = page.getPixmap() AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'getPixmap'. Did you mean: 'get_pixmap'?`
well, then if i change getPixmap to get_pixmap I get the following error:

```
`AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site
packages\tkPDFViewer\tkPDFViewer.py", line 48, in 
add_imgimg = pix1.getImageData("ppm")
AttributeError: 'Pixmap' object has no attribute 'getImageData'`
```

A lot of people need some help from tkPDFViewer's owner. but what I want is, pip community have to delete this tkPDFViewer library, because it has no a preview version, it is the only version the owner release, then if the very first release doesn't work, it means the owner have not tested his code before pushing it into production. the owner should have specified versions for any change made in the code rather than pushing the code in differing method to bypass pip version controller. and that change of GETPIXMAP should be considered as mayor change of version.
here I'm using the library:

```
`# Importing tkinter to make gui in python

from tkinter import*

# Importing tkPDFViewer to place pdf file in gui.
# In tkPDFViewer library there is
# an tkPDFViewer module. That I have imported as pdf

from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf

# Initializing tk

root = Tk()

# Set the width and height of our root window.

root.geometry("550x750")

# creating object of ShowPdf from tkPDFViewer.

v1 = pdf.ShowPdf()

# Adding pdf location and width and height.

v2 = v1.pdf_view(root,pdf_location = r"simplepdf.pdf",width = 
50,height = 100)

# Placing Pdf in my gui.

v2.pack()

root.mainloop()`
```